# How can I apply a 2D mask in numpy but keep the structure of the rows?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays e.g.:

```
names = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])        # (B, 1)
mask = np.array([                             # (N, B)
    [True, False, False, False],
    [False, True, False, True ],
    [True, True, False, False]
])
```

I want to get an 1 dimensional array of lists with shape `(N,)`, where for each row in `mask` I have a list of the names in `names` for which the value was `True`. Here that would be:

```
result = [
    ['A'],
    ['B', 'C'],
    ['A', 'B']
]
```

Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each array `m` in `mask`, you can subset `names` based on the values of `m`.

```
[list(names[m]) for m in mask]

# [['A'], ['B', 'D'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Comment: Yup. That was worked. Should have thought of that.